# Creating a mask over an existing ExtJS panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a hbox layout that contains two panels. Each panel contains a form. My requirement is to create a mask on every panel when the user clicks a button or a certain condition is met. The idea is to make the forms look like inactive while not hiding them. How can I place a mask over all panels individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable forms.

```
form.disable()
```

And you have a property `maskOnDisable`. If you set it to true you have the visual effect you want.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/P95Ug/)

Here some [documentation](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-property-maskOnDisable)

Comment: Didn't know it is that simple. Thanks a lot.